# Delphi SQLite Wrapper with Static Linking and Encryption support

Tags: delphi, encryption, sqlite, delphi-xe2, anydac

I need a wrapper for SQLite which supports static linking and has at least some basic encryption support (also, preferably free)

To summarize what I've found so far

[ZeosLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) - Supports encryption. Doesn't support static linking.

[AduCom](http://www.aducom.com/) - Website is down mostly

[AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) - Can't find any pricing or purchase link for AnyDAC as it was bought by Embarcadero and turned to FireDAC ?

[LiteDAC](http://www.devart.com/litedac/editions.html) - Provides Static Linking. Standard Edition (~$130) doesn't provide encryption. Professional Edition (~$200)

[DISQLite3](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/feature_chart) - Supports Static Linking and Encryption. Free for Personal Use (with limited features). Professional (~150 Euro)

[Synopse mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) - Supports static linking. Not sure about encryption. But I cannot get my head around this framework. ORM, SOA, UI, PDF, SQLite combined into one humongous framework. Now I have no idea how to use only the SQLite part with static linking. There seems to be some explanation around it https://stackoverflow.com/a/4971398/605027 but I'm not sure if it still applies.

The best wrapper I've found so far is the [SQLite3-Delphi-FPC](https://github.com/plashenkov/SQLite3-Delphi-FPC). Very minimalist and straight-forward to use. Ideally, I'd like to continue using the same wrapper with Synopse's static linking abilities and some kind of basic encryption. Any pointers to how this can be achieved ?

**P.S.** I do not want to embed sqlite3.dll in resources and load it dynamically during execution.

**N.B.**: *There are a lot of questions and hence a lot of confusion floating around regarding this topic. So I felt the need for posting a new question*

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Synopse mORMot with all my lastest projects. It's free and open source, has good support of the author by the forum. Supports static linking of SQLite DLL and encryption by AES. Besides, you can use it on server/client application over the HTTP protocol. Yes, the framework is very big and has many functions but you don't need to use all of them. I use only a small part in my applications without any problem.
Maybe it's a little bit complicated to start with (I'm not a Delphi Expert) but after this your possibilities are limitless.

Comment: Encryption is available since 2010 with mORMot's sqlite3 unit. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/14/SQLite3-Framework-version-1.5#c8828590  See also http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/02/25/Using-external-MinGW/VisualC-sqlite3.dll-including-benchmark

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of mORMot and it doesn't contain any file named SynSQLite3Static.pas as described in that blog post. How do I get SQLite to statically link ?

Comment: Download last version from "Timeline" menu and you will find SynSQLite3Static.pas, the current "beta" version is a bit different from last stable version. However the "timeline" version works very well.

Answer (score 2):

There may no longer be a need to use 3rd party wrappers for SQLite anymore.

In Delphi XE3, Embarcadero added direct support for SQLite using the dbExpress and FireDAC frameworks. Then in Delphi XE5, they enhanced that and added comprehensive support for SQLite through the FireDAC library, which includes even "smart" datatype recognition.

FireDAC is now [the recommended Database Access Library for Delphi](http://delphi.org/2013/12/firedac-is-recommended/), replacing dbExpress and others.

The last section in the Embarcadero docwiki article: [Using SQLite with FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC) indicates how to use the FireDAC SQLite API wrapping classes which is used by the FireDAC SQLite driver if you need to get the maximum SQLite data access performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a plain and simple sqlite3.dll wrapper once because I didn't find what I needed in existing solutions also: [TSQLite](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite).

I read [here](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki) that you can compile a dedicated sqlite3.dll with encryption, and/or(?) need to use `sqlite3_activate_see` and `sqlite3_key_v2` but I haven't written those in my wrapper (probably because this made my wrapper fail on the default sqlite3.dll). If this is what you need translating from sqlite3.h is not that hard and the current SQLite.pas has loads of examples.